# TypeError: object() takes no parameters is encountered when practicing basic pytorch dataloader

Tags: pytorch, typeerror

[image]

Dear all pro:

I tried the tutorial in the link of https://pythonprogramming.net/training-deep-learning-neural-network-pytorch/?completed=/building-deep-learning-neural-network-pytorch/ and played around with the code on the google colab notebook.

The part of importing and dataloading the MNIST dataset is fine. But when i tried to iterate through the dataset , it complained the error showed in the picture. I do not understand why this happend.

Comment: I runned above code in google colab enviroment. Now i installed the pytorch on my local server and run the same code. The result and optimizer work fine. I do not  understand why google colab complained this.

Answer (score 0):

`transforms.ToTensor` is a class, you have to instantiate it.

The first two lines should be (with explicit imports):

```
import torchvision

train = torchvision.datasets.MNIST(
    "",
    train=True,
    download=True,
    # See below class is instantiated
    transform=torchvision.transforms.Compose([torchvision.transforms.ToTensor()]),
)


test = torchvision.datasets.MNIST(
    "",
    train=False,
    download=True,
    transform=torchvision.transforms.Compose([torchvision.transforms.ToTensor()]),
)
```

BTW. If you only have a single transformation there is no need for `torchvision.transforms.Compose`.